# Does the superconducting current lose energy by means of radiation?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, superconductivity

Superconducting circular currents can last for years. Don't they lose energy by EM radiation, as every circular current does? Or are there simply no lower energy levels for the electrons to fall into? The radiation would be of a very low frequency I guess. If it really exists, which is my question.

Comment: It appears that the deeper question is whether and if not why not the electrons radiate, as they are accelerated due to circular motion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Don't they loose energy by EM radiation, as every circular current does?

A steady (DC) circular current does not lose energy by EM radiation, regardless of whether it is a superconducting loop or a resistive loop. There is a magnetic field, and that magnetic field does contain energy, but the energy stays in the near field and does not radiate off to the far field.

You may be thinking of synchrotron radiation which is produced by accelerating particle bunches as they turn in a particle accelerator. That is not equivalent. Particle bunches are not steady and cannot be treated like a DC current.

Comment: Yes, off course. There is no changing field in a circular current. Even when the electrons are accelerated towards the center, they are not accelerated linearly.

Comment: @Vielloosoof But is this true on a microscopic level? At some point, $rho({\bf, r}', t_r)$ is lumpy, and thus changes. Yet super currents last for years.

Comment: What about a CW stored beam? The lab-frame sees a constant charge density and constant current. Would it radiate?

Comment: @JEB In the case of a supercurrent I think the superconducting state is an eigenstate which are not radiating unless there is a lower energy state. Im not sure if there is a lower energy state. A stored beam? Eehhm... I dont know.

Comment: @JEB it is not as lumpy as you might think. Electrons are not little classical point charges. They are spatially distributed over their wavefunction. This can actually be surprisingly large, large enough to get rid of any lumpiness. E.g. the radius for a Cooper pair electron can be about 100 nm which covers about 80 units of the superconductor lattice. I don’t know the similar numbers for an ordinary conductor

Comment: @Dale It wouldn't be the 1st time that quantum mechanics prevented a system, that by classical considerations _must_ radiate, from radiating.

Answer (score 0):

A supercurrent cannot lose any energy, because the electron pairs, as bosons, form the Bose-Einstein-Condensate (BEC). The energy of every boson in the BEC is minimum and quantized, so below a certain temperature each boson cannot emit any energy.